# CSS Grayscale with Opacity

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Is it possible to use the grayscale filter with a set transparency?

This works fine in non-IE browsers, but the grayscale filter seems to bring the opacity back up to 100% in IE8+

```
.disabled{
   opacity: .2; /* standard: ff gt 1.5, opera, safari */
   -ms-filter: “alpha(opacity=20)”; /* ie 8 */
   filter: alpha(opacity=20); /* ie lt 7 */
   -khtml-opacity: .2; /* safari 1.x */
   -moz-opacity: .2; /* ff lt 1.5, netscape */


   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: Is this a self answering question? You've tried it and the answer is no..?

Comment: Did you try it the other way around?  I mean, inside your rule, specify the filter first and then the opacity.

Comment: I thought you could chain them `filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(50%;` is that what you mean?

Comment: Still not able to get both the opacity and gray values to show up in IE. Seems to be one or the other.

Comment: There are smart quotes in `-ms-filter`, they are not valid, use `"`s instead.